# Using eval with wildcard in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependency-management

Borne out of morbid curiosity and seeing CMake's ExternalProject, I've tried to hack up a cute little attempt at an automatic git-dependency manager for a C++ project, however I can't quite make Make dance the way I want it to.

```
# shortname, git address, configure, make (install), make clean
DEPENDENCIES:=\
    catch,https://github.com/philsquared/Catch.git,true,true,true
, := ,

hit_subtree = git subtree $1 --prefix deps/$2 $2 master --squash
define get_or_update
    $(if $(wildcard deps/$1/*),
        git fetch $1 master && $(call hit_subtree,pull,$1),
        $(if $(shell git ls-remote catch),
            true,
            git remote add -f $1 $2) && $(call hit_subtree,add,$1)
    )
endef
update_cxx_flags = $$(if $$(wildcard deps/$1/include/*),$$(eval CXXFLAGS += -Ideps/$1/include),)
update_ld_flags  = $$(if $$(wildcard deps/$1/lib/*),$$(eval LDFLAGS += -Ideps/$1/lib),)
define update_flags 
    $(eval $(call update_cxx_flags,$1))
    export CXXFLAGS
    $(eval $(call update_ld_flags,$1))
    export LDFLAGS
endef
build_project = cd deps/$1 && $4 && $2 && $3

define git_dependency
    $(call get_or_update,$1,$2)
    $(call build_project,$1,$3,$4,$5)
    $(call update_flags,$1)
endef
caller = $(call git_dependency,$(word 1,$1),$(word 2,$1),$(word 3,$1),$(word 4,$1),$(word 5,$1))

git_dependencies:
    $(foreach dep,$(DEPENDENCIES),$(call caller,$(subst $(,), ,$(dep))))
    @echo ${CXXFLAGS}
    @echo ${LDFLAGS}
```

The problem lies in the update_flags function: specifically, update_flags tries to modify `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to account for new include/lib dirs however it seems that `$(eval ...)` isn't doing what I want it do. On the first run (i.e. when the directory is first being cloned) the `$(wildcard ...)` function sees no sub-directories of `deps/$1` however if I invoke `make` a second time it then works fine. To me, this suggests that `$(eval ...)` isn't *actually* evaluating `update_cxx_flags` and instead the function is being non-lazily evaluated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if I look at this, the first thing I will do, is isolate the problem, narrow down to as few lines as possible, and replace the irrelevant tools that I may not have, with tools that everybody has.  In other words, I will attempt to produce an SSCCE and then solve the problem.  Would you care to do this yourself so I don't have to?

Comment: I can't quite work out what you mean -- I'm relatively certain that the problem lies on either line 15 or 18 (and 16/19 is just a copy-paste with a word changed). I know when the problem occurs (when the directory is first cloned, it doesn't work, otherwise it does) and I've done my best to provide the smallest complete example that can be copy-pasted and run to exhibit my bug. The only thing I can't (yet) do is solve this problem, because I understand little about Make. What exactly is it you think I'm missing, here?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "can be copy-pasted" ??? When run as originally posted, this won't run at all because git can't access anything, even though I have git on command line.  For you, maybe, but not for me.  For me `git fetch catch master` simply fails.  If you want, please tell me, what initialization do I need to do first, so that, `git fetch catch master` will succeed.  Then perhaps I can run your full `Makefile`.

Comment: hmm, so maybe I misunderstand even more about make than I thought -- specifically, `git fetch catch master` shouldn't run *until* `git remote add -f $1 $2` is run, which adds the remote catch. This makes it even stranger, then, since this works fine for me.

Comment: And another question.  You say "smallest complete example".  Are you really sure, there is no smaller example that has lines 15-18 that will exhibit the bug? I am pretty sure there is :)

Comment: Since you know about `git` and I have `git` , and the very first thing that runs, is `git fetch catch master` and it fails, then you better tell me, what init to do, so it passes.  You are the `git` expert, you tell me.

Comment: I think I got it, I did `git init` and now the thing runs.  Hold on a second Mister I will tell you where your problem is.

Comment: well now `git subtree` failed, no such git command.  Which version of `git` do you have? Mine is 1.7.4.4

Comment: git 1.9.1, which is just the stock standard in 14.04.1 LTS ubuntu's repo. My `get_or_update` command should, in theory, be running the command `git remote add -f $1 $2 && $(call hit_subtree,add,$1)` (line 12) if the directory deps/catch doesn't exist (which it shouldn't if you haven't run the script before). I'm not sure how this isn't being run -- unless the wildcard function is returning true?

Comment: Of course, this is under the assumption you're running within a git repo, which I should have mentioned.

Comment: OK I will withdraw my answer and give you a second one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62398/discussion-between-mark-galeck-and-ben-stott).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your SSCCE:

```
all:
    touch foobar
    echo $(wildcard foobar)
```

This 'does not work', as you observe, first time, but second time, it works.  Why?  Because, GNU Make *first* evaluates the whole recipe, before executing any lines of it.  Then, after the recipe is evaluated (translated into the shell language), only then it is executed.

OK, you wanted to do it with `$$`, it still won't work, the double `$` won't make it defer to the recipe execution, it will just evaluate twice during the processing of `eval`:

```
all:                                                                            
        touch foobar                                                            
        $(eval $$(info $$(wildcard foobar)))
```

On the chat, I told you what is happening, but you are assuming some "caching".

You are a very knowledgeable person in certain areas, but you must remember when you learn something new, to start from the beginning and follow simple examples and manual.  I am giving you simple examples, analyze them with the help of the manual and do not spin your own theories.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer led me to google to work out why `$(eval $$(wildcard foobar))` wouldn't behave as intended -- after all, at the very least [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) promises to evaluate the argument as though it was 'typed' into your makefile.

It turns out that `$(wildcard ...)` is a little too smart for its own good: it caches directories and only updates the cache if a file is generated via a makefile rule. In this instance, the file is generated by dropping to shell and using git which violates the assumption that files are generated via makefile rules. Thus, the check in `update_cxx_flags` is incorrect (as well as `update_ld_flags`). Instead, it should be modified as so:

```
update_cxx_flags = $$(if `ls deps/$1/include/* 2>/dev/null`,$$(eval CXXFLAGS += -Ideps/$1/include),)
```

where the `/dev/null` clobber is so that an error message doesn't appear when the file doesn't exist. This makes the makefile behave as expected, which is what I wanted!

Comment: Ben if it works for you man, great, but let me tell you, what you are doing is terribly complicated, unnecessarily so, and you are refusing to learn step by step and do things that are simple.  I wish you luck.